# Connect to CCTV camera with easy_onvif Flutter

Tags: flutter, ip-camera, onvif

I have an ezviz h8c camera. I'm trying to access this camera from my flutter app to get the stream and control the movement of the camera.
I have been able to get the stream with a RTSP url with vlc_player package.
For control the movement of the camera I was trying out easy_onvif package from pub.dev.
But when I try to connect with the onvif.connect command its showing DioException error.
This is the code I have been trying to connect with the camera to control the movement.

```
      Future<void> connect({required String ip}) async {
    try {
      onvif = await Onvif.connect(
        host: ip,
        username: 'admin', // Replace with your username
        password: 'password', // Replace with your password
      );

      log(' ✅ OnVIFService: connected to $ip');

      await getToken(); // Fetch token after successful connection
    } catch (error) {
      log(' ✅ OnVIFService: connection error: $error');
    }
  }
```

From here I was calling the function

```
    onPressed: () async {
          await onvifService
              .connect(ip: '192.168.0.103')
              .then((value) => onvifService.moveLeft());
          debugPrint("working");
          onvifService.getToken();
        }
```

But when I'm trying to connect the camera the following error is showing.

> I/flutter ( 6295): ‼️ 13:20:06.161941 ERROR    UI Loggy - LoggingInterceptors - ERROR:
> I/flutter ( 6295): DioException [connection timeout]: The request connection took longer than 0:00:20.000000 and it was aborted. To get rid of this exception, try raising the RequestOptions.connectTimeout above the duration of 0:00:20.000000 or improve the response time of the server.
> I/flutter ( 6295): working
> [log]  ✅ OnVIFService: connection error: Exception: DioException [connection timeout]: The request connection took longer than 0:00:20.000000 and it was aborted. To get rid of this exception, try raising the RequestOptions.connectTimeout above the duration of 0:00:20.000000 or improve the response time of the server.
> [log] OnVIFService: token is not set
> [log] OnVIFService: got token null

Can anyone suggest to me how to fix this error and connect with my camera to control the ptz with easy_onvif package?
Thank you
If it helps below there I give the code to get the stream which works fine.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';

import '../widgets/onvif_button.dart';

/// Stateful widget to fetch and then display video content.
class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoApp({super.key});

  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  late VlcPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = VlcPlayerController.network(
        "rtsp://admin:password@192.168.0.103/H.264",
        autoPlay: true)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height * 0.3,
          child: VlcPlayer(
            controller: _controller,
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9, // Adjust aspect ratio as needed
            placeholder: const Center(
                child:
                    CircularProgressIndicator()), // Optional loading indicator
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height * 0.1,
          child: OnvifButton(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

With a nmap scan I found out ezviz h8c camera has 554, 8000, 9010 port is open.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and my solution was to configure my IP
My camera is a Tapo C310 and this is the IP http://ip_here:2020/onvif/device_service